# how to create a report comment button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, comments, report

i have a page where users will be able to comment on the content but i would like to create a report button where users can report user for any reason.

the comments is retrieved via a grid-view and i am using asp.net 4.0

thanks

Comment: do you want to store the report in database ...

Comment: @errorstacks - Yes i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I all i had to do was use a link button like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lnkReportComment" runat="Server" Text="Report" CommandName="ReportComment" CommandArgument='<%#HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("ID"))%>' OnClick="lnkReportComment_Click" />
```

and then i added my code to the code-behind:

```
protected void lnkReportComment_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
//add your code
```

and it worked.